# Xamarin.Forms build error

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I just got a new Xamarin.Forms portable project in Visual Studio, and I'm trying to run it on the VM.
When I run it, this error appears:

[Error encountered while loading the project...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aUvN.png)

How do I fix it? Every project I start has this error.

Comment: it sounds like you have a bad or incomplete installation of Xamarin

Comment: do i need to reinstall it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of 2 possibilities here where I've faced such problem

> 1. Broken/ incomplete downloaded zips

This may have occurred because you cancelled or closed the VS out of frustration because it was taking too much time.

while in fact the visual studio is downloading the zips at `AppData/Local/Xamarin/zips`. because you closed visual studio, the zip files are not completely downloaded.

what you do is go to `AppData/Local/Xamarin/zips` delete all the zip files then `AppData/Local/Xamarin` you should only see Universal, zips and logs folders delete the rest. wait for the zips to install completely. this is gonna take time for sure.

> 2. Problem with the References

Check if any of the references are showing any warning sign or something. if so remove the reference and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

1. Close your project
2. Locate the project's *.suo file and delete it (it may be a hidden file, don't remember)
3. Reload your project